# How to pass value to PS3 prompt non-interactively?

Tags: bash, shell

I've got an interactive script to which I should pass some value non-interactively

Interactive script prints the 'list of choices' using 'PS3' variable

```
PS3='Select the platform to use:'
```

ex output is shown below

```
echo 'Linux Build System initializing'

 1) Linux PC based
 2) ABC 1
 3) XYZ 4

Select the platform to use: <waits for user input>
```

I'd like to pass the value to the PS3 prompt.  Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`select`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/user_select) built-in to achieve this,

```
PS3='Select the platform to use: '
select choice in $(seq 3)
do
    [[ $choice -eq 1 ]] && echo "Linux PC based"
    [[ $choice -eq 2 ]] && echo "ABC 1"
    [[ $choice -eq 3 ]] && echo "XYZ 4"
    break
done
```

make sure to `export` the `PS3` value in `~/.bashrc` to make it permanent. Also worth adding a point, `select` is not a `POSIX` compatible option and may not be portable across platforms.

The way you can call this in one-script and invoke in another is by wrapping the above code in a function and `source` it in another file. On the original script, e.g. say `script1.sh`, wrapping in function as

```
#!/bin/bash

function optselect() {
    arg1=$1
    select arg1 in $(seq 3)
    do
        [[ $arg1 -eq 1 ]] && echo "Linux PC based"
        [[ $arg1 -eq 2 ]] && echo "ABC 1"
        [[ $arg1 -eq 3 ]] && echo "XYZ 4"    
        break
    done
}
```

Then in the calling script e.g. say `script2.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./script1.sh
optselect 1            # Calling the script with argument '1'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  But, I need to call this script from another script.  I need to pass value to 'SELECT' from calling script

Comment: @SathishKumar: pass it as a argument to from one script other,  and use `select $1 in $(seq 3)`, hope you can do that

Comment: Thank you.  Let me try that

Comment: You probably don't want to call `break` unconditionally, as it doesn't give the user the opportunity to enter a value between 1 and 3 if they failed to do so the first time.

Comment: @chepner: Agreed, mine was one-time prompt response only, it could be couple with each option `&& break` right?

Comment: I'd use a `case` statement with a `*) continue` branch, then place the unconditional `break` after the `case` statement.

Comment: @chepner: That guarantees `POSIX` as well, feel free to update as a separate answer or mine! Will to it in some time

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` statement inside a `select` statement. The `case` statement will use `continue` to return to the top of the `select` statement if an invalid choice is made. Otherwise, use `break` *after* the `case` statement to exit the `select` loop.

```
PS3='Select the platform to use: '
select choice in "Linux PC based"  "ABC 1" "XYZ 4"
do
    case $choice in
      1) echo "You chose Linux" ;;
      2) echo "You chose ABC" ;;
      3) echo "You chose XYZ" ;;
      *) continue
    esac
    break
done
```